# How do streams / fork-join access arrays thread-safely?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, java-8

Streams and fork-join both provide functionality to parallelize code that accesses arrays. For example, `Arrays.parallelSetAll` is implemented largely by the following line:

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length).parallel()
    .forEach(i -> { array[i] = generator.applyAsLong(i); });
```

Also, the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveAction.html) of `RecursiveAction`, part of the fork-join framework, contains the following example:

```
static class SortTask extends RecursiveAction {
    final long[] array; final int lo, hi;
    ...
    void merge(int lo, int mid, int hi) {
        long[] buf = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, lo, mid);
        for (int i = 0, j = lo, k = mid; i < buf.length; j++)
            array[j] = (k == hi || buf[i] < array[k]) ?
                buf[i++] : array[k++];
    }
}
```

Finally, parallel streams created from arrays access the arrays in multiple threads (the code is too complex to summarize here).

All of these examples appear to read from or write to arrays without any synchronization or other memory barriers (as far as I can tell). As we know, completely ad hoc multithreaded array accesses are unsafe as there is no guarantee that a read reflects a write in another thread unless there is a happens-before relationship between the read and the write. In fact, the `Atomic...Array` classes were created specifically to address this issue. However, given that each example above is in the standard library or its documentation, I presume they're correct.

Can someone please explain what mechanism guarantees the safety of the array accesses in these examples?

Comment: Note that two threads aren't operating on the _same_ array entries; they don't overlap.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Regardless, how does the thread that calls `parallelSetAll` or that invokes `SortTask` see the writes made within them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: partitioning.

The JMM is defined in terms of access to *variables*.  Variables include static fields, instance fields, and array elements.  If you arrange your program such that thread T0 is the only thread to access element 0 of an array, and similarly T1 is the only thread to access element 1 of an array, then each of these elements is effectively thread-confined, and you have no problem -- the JMM program order rule takes care of you.

Parallel streams build on this principle.  Each task is working on a segment of the array that no other task is working on.  Then all we have to do is ensure that the thread running a task can see the initial state of the array, and the consumer of the final result can see the as-modified-by-the-task view of the appropriate section of the array.  These are easily arranged through synchronization actions embedded in the implementation of the parallel stream and FJ libraries.

Comment: Brian, thank you for your answer. But you gloss over the heart of it. What synchronization actions can achieve the required visibility semantics? You can't synchronize on a single array element, nor mark it volatile, and synchronizing on the whole array would defeat parallelism. I believe `java.util.concurrent.locks` have the same semantics.

Comment: You don't have to synchronize _on the array element_ in order to guarantee its visibility.  You merely need a _happens-before_ edge between the writer and the reader.  In addition to the obvious mechanisms (`synchronized` and `volatile`), many concurrent library abstractions provide consistency guarantees.  For example, the `Future` class specification says: "Actions taken by the asynchronous computation _happen-before_ actions following the corresponding `Future.get()` in another thread."  Similar guarantees are provided by `BlockingQueue`, `ConcurrentHashMap`, `ForkJoinTask`, etc.

Comment: You are right and I didn't mean to imply `synchronized` and `volatile` are the *only* ways to guarantee visibility. I guess I am assuming that library classes that provide the concurrency guarantees that you mention are implemented in terms of certain primitives and I am not aware of a primitive that provides the desired concurrency. For example `Atomic*Array` classes call down to `Unsafe.put...` but the examples in the OP access the arrays directly. I asked this question after examining the code but I will peruse it further.

Comment: See the section on "Memory consistency guarantees" on the j.u.c. package javadoc, for example.

Comment: @Solomonoff's Secret: maybe you haven’t understood the *transitivity* property of *happens-before* relationships. E.g. the sequence “thread A writes value X to an array” → “thread A writes `true` to a `volatile` variable `done`” → “thread B reads `true` from the same `done` variable” → “thread B reads the value X from the array” is sufficient for the visibility of X to thread B, regarding what A did before setting `done` to `true`.